# R Bar chart plotting

Tags: r

I am attempting to use R for some password analysis, specifically what characters are at the beginning and end of a short list (50 passwords) as shown below.

```
> dput(Final_DF$Pswd)
c("monkey", "iloveyou", "dragon", "jbI2pnK$xi", "password", "computer", 
"!qessw", "tUNh&SSm6!", "sunshine", "wYrUeWV", "superman", "samsung", 
"utoXGe6$", "master", "wjZC&OvXX", "0R1cNTm9sGir", "Fbuu2bs89?", 
"pokemon", "secret", "x&W1TjO59", "buster", "purple", "shine", 
"flower", "marina", "Tg%OQT$0", "SbDUV&nOX", "peanut", "angel", 
"?1LOEc4Zfk", "computer", "spiderman", "nothing", "$M6LgmQgv$", 
"orange", "knight", "american", "outback", "TfuRpt3PiZ", "air", 
"surf", "lEi2a$$eyz", "date", "V$683rx$p", "newcastle", "estate", 
"foxy", "ginger", "coffee", "legs")
```

I can plot the characters at the beginning by

```
#plot what characters are at the end on a graph

fact1 <- table(str_extract(Final_DF$Pswd, "[[:punct:]]$"))
fact2 <- table(str_extract(Final_DF$Pswd, "[[:digit:]]$"))
fact3 <- table(str_extract(Final_DF$Pswd, "[[:lower:]]$"))
fact4 <- table(str_extract(Final_DF$Pswd, "[[:upper:]]$"))

barplot(c(fact1, fact2, fact3, fact4))
```

[image: bar plot showing count of characters at the end of passwords]

However when I do the same for the characters at the beginning, I appear to be missing some characters along the x axis

```
fact5 <- table(str_extract(Final_DF$Pswd, "^[[:punct:]]"))
fact6 <- table(str_extract(Final_DF$Pswd, "^[[:digit:]]"))
fact7 <- table(str_extract(Final_DF$Pswd, "^[[:lower:]]"))
fact8 <- table(str_extract(Final_DF$Pswd, "^[[:upper:]]"))

barplot(c(fact5, fact6, fact7, fact8))
```

[image: bar plot showing count of characters at the beginning of passwords]

Anybody any ideas what is happening please?

Comment: looking at my password list the following characters appear to be missing p.w,F,b,T,n,$,e

Comment: Are you comparing fact3 and fact7

Comment: You're using the preview window, just rescale it with your mouse.